# Error while sending ajax request in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, json

my client side code sending ajax request

```
var taskDetail = {
            Id: id,
            StatusTo: "Completed", //should come from list of status to change 
            Description: description,
            Documents: document,
            Visibility: visibility
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: url_link.task_complete + JSON.stringify(taskDetail),
            type: "GET",
            success: function (e) {

                $('#Task-Status').html(e.Status);
                $('.desc-entry').hide();
                $('.desc-note').find('span').html(e.Description);
                $('#Task-Completion').html(DateHelper(e.CurrentCompletionDate));
                $('.comp-date').show();
                $('.desc-note').show();

                /*
                 * Change status
                 * hide text area
                 * show description
                 * hide complete button
                 * 
                 */

                $('.thumb').find('ul').empty();
                $('#description').val('');


                $('.desc-button').hide();
                updateTaskDocument(taskDetail.Id);
                //updateProjectPoint(taskDetail.Id);
            },
            error: function (xhrRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("Error while sending request");
            }
        });
```

my server side code

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    [Route("status")]
    public IHttpActionResult ChangeTaskStatus(string task)
    {
        ChangeStatusViewModel status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChangeStatusViewModel>(task);
        int result = repo.ChangeStatus(status);
        if (result < 1)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

       // mail.Send(db.GetUserList(db.GetGroup(status.Id)));

        var detail = repo.GetTaskDetail(status.Id);
        return Ok(detail);
    }
```

Getting error

> An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information:

> Error converting value {null} to type 'System.Int32'. Path 'Documents[1]', line 1, position 107.

please help me

Comment: The error clearly mentions that some Field in the `ChangeStatusViewModel` is an `int` but the value that sent in the ajax request is null. Looking at the data you send to the server the only problematic field might be the ID field. Check if it actually contains any value or try making the Id field of `ChangeStatusViewModel` to `int?`

Comment: but this is my model 
    public class ChangeStatusViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string StatusTo { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public List<int> Documents { get; set; }
   
        public bool Visibility { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Yes but when JsoonSerialization tries to deserialize a json object into a .net object and if none of the properties of the .net type are non-nullable. you would get htis exception. Try changing the `public int Id {get;set;}` to `public int? Id {get;set;}`

Answer (score 0):

MVC Model Binding will do the work for you. You can submit your data without using "**JSON.stringify**" and make sure that filed in "**taskDetail**" are the same as "**ChangeStatusViewMode**"

```
$.ajax({
    url: url_link.task_complete,
    data : taskDetail,
    type: "GET",
    dataType : 'json',
    success: function (e) {
    }
});

public IHttpActionResult ChangeTaskStatus(ChangeStatusViewModel  taskDetail)
{}
```